# Xamarin.Android Break Mode

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

I tried to build an app with sqllite and customized listitem in `xamarin.android` and when debug app in emulator with **Android** 4.4 to 5.0 it works but for later version i got this exception:

the application is in break mode

Unhandled Exception:

> System.NotSupportedException: Could not activate JNI Handle 0xff9fbfd8
>   (key_handle 0x68ca6f2) of Java type
>   'md53f5ae0e0cc50f8da65fc6fa54158c506/MainActivity' as managed type
>   'Gardeshgar.MainActivity'.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e5cju.png)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @B.zarei,Please provide one demo that can reproduce your issue here by lvan's link